# ASP.NET MVC 5 jQuery UI autocomplete search box

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create search box which show results when user is typing in.

I have the following in my partial view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "inputCat", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter category name...", @spellcheck = "true" } })
```

In my main view where I load the partial view I have:

```
$('#inputCat').autocomplete({
    source: 'Editor/SearchCategory'
});
```

Here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult SearchCategory(string term)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    return Json(db.Categories.Where(cat => cat.CategoryName.StartsWith(term)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I type in the input field in the browser console I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:port/Editor/SearchCategory?term=s 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I cannot understand where is the problem.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
I needed to create new routing in the RouteConfig.cs file.
Then I change the source to use '@Html.Action("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName")'
This worked like a charm for me :)
Hope this helps someone else who is in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

i would add comment but i cant yet.

please post more details because HTTP 500 can mean a lot of things

Have you looked at browser developer tools network tab for details of error ?

Have you tried to debug it and get exception details ?

maybe turn off `customErrors` in `web.config` to get YSOD with details about problem, and post them here.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.
I have checked the Network tab /section Preview/ on my browser. And I thin maybe I understand what is happening. But I have a question: If my input field is in form that is posting data to some other controller action, can this autocomplete method from jQuery UI post the form?

Comment: i don't understand. please clarify. autocomplete does not "Submit" form it makes AJAX request

Comment: My input field, on which I use the jQuery UI autocmpolete method, is in form. I am posting the form to action method in one of my controllers. When I checked the Network tab and clicked the error another window with Preview tab showed. I clicked on that Preview tab and I got a detailed page with the error. I saw that my form was posted and because I have parameters that are passed as 'null', which I am processing afterwards, I thought that the error is related to that. So that is why I asked if autocomplete method can post my form "accidentally". Hope I was More clear now.

Comment: from my knowledge autocomplete should not post form. look what is in response of that 500 request, maybe there is information what happened and post it

Comment: Thanks for your help I will struggle with this a bit more :) Sorry I cannot vote this as answer =\